# Show Line Number in Error Message

Tags: matlab, runtime-error

On most instances of MATLAB I've used, whenever I had a bug in my code the error message in the command window would show the line number.

However on the computer I am currently using, it shows me only the following:

`??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.`

Is there anyway to get the line number to show again instead of `????`?

Comment: Can you show one screenshot as the line number usually will display below such error message?

Comment: Matlab shows the line when running a script, but not when running commands directly on the command window

Comment: @LuisMendo, I am using scripts for sure.

Comment: @herohuyongtao here's a screenshot: http://s17.postimg.org/4hf0sr56n/Untitled.png

Comment: @msmf14 This image is too small to see. :(

Comment: @herohuyongtao interesting, its really large on my screen :). in either case the only output is the line i quoted above.

Comment: How are you running the script?  If you use Run Section or Run and Advance, you will not see line numbers in your error messages.

Comment: It looks as if you have a `clc` command in your script. Comment it out, run the script and it should show the line number.

Comment: @canzar you were absolutely right, I was only running sections of the script. I searched online for this and couldnt find it. Would you mind submitting it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is using `Run Section` or `Run and Advance` as @canzar said. If you run scripts like this there is no 'line number', just as when you copy-paste code and run it in the command-window will not show you the line number on the error.

If you run the script using `run` or by pressing F5 it *does* know the line number and then prints that on the error statement. Good to know for debugging is to go to the tab editor->breakpoints->dbstop on error. If you press that it will keep your variables as present when the memory occurs, as opposed to throwing everything out when debugging functions.

Comment: Can the error message be modified for showing the error number?

Comment: @hyprfrco what do you mean by "error number"? In MATLAB errors don't have numbers, they simply are a message stating what's wrong. The only numbers you'll (regularly) find in an error message is the line number.

Comment: No i mean the error line... i still think it is possible, obviously not when the executed line is in the workspace, or even under that case

Comment: The run command is applied only under a file hence there is always a line number associated to it

Comment: @hyprfrco Well, if you run the script (any which way), it'll show a line number. If you run it in the command window (either which way I mentioned), it can't show a line number, simple as that. So what is your actual question then?

Comment: The question applies when you run scripts... with several lines in it, typically when you are debugging... i find it illogical why mathworks do not report it

Comment: Normally a function would have, 200-500 lines each, and a piece of code could have... 30-50?....

Comment: @hyprfrco I would guess that when you're executing only part of a script file, the interpreter only gets the relevant block of code, so it has no way of finding out the true line numbers. Why pass all the 500 lines of code of you're evaluating a single line, or a 5-line code cell? But since the line numbers can't be deduced reliably, it's safer not to show them at all. This would be my guess. Anything other than a guess can only come from Mathworks, so feel free to contact their support.

Comment: @hyprfrco if you indeed run a "section" (which is separated by a single line started by `%%` and, in default white background, turns yellow when you're typing in it) from the editor, it basically runs that as separate code from the command window, just not actually copying it to your history. So what Andras says applies, you need to contact TMW with a feature request.