# MATLAB Debugger no longer showing line numbers

Tags: matlab, debugging, line-numbers

I'm not entirely sure how, but my copy of MATLAB R2013b has stopped showing which line my errors occur at.

I'll just get errors like:

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

But no line number to go along with it, so I have no idea which part of my code is causing the problem!

Did I mess up a setting somewhere?

Comment: What happens when you create another obvious error? Do you get a line number?  How are you running the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable line numbering in the editor with Preferences -> Editor/Debugger -> Display -> Show line numbers

When running code segments (for example, using Ctrl+Enter with the Windows default key bindings), line numbers will not be displayed. You can see the line on which the error is caused by directly running the script or calling the function in which it occurs.

Comment: Yeah, that'll turn on line numbers in my editor, but my debugger output still doesn't have line numbers.

Comment: Ah, I see. This happens if you run code segments with Ctrl+Enter (or see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316101/show-line-number-in-error-message-matlab)). Otherwise it's rather strange.

Comment: Here you go, glad to help :)