# Matlab: How to debug a script (showing line number with error)

Tags: matlab, debugging

When an error occurs when running a script completely, the the error will show the line number on which the error occurred. However, I use 'run section' (control-enter on Windows) *a lot* during writing of scripts & functions and then any error appears without line number.

This bugs me (pun intended) because there is really no good reason for this behavior. This question was raised previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316101/show-line-number-in-error-message-matlab), but I find the answer very unsatisfactory: 'it is just so, like using the command line'.
I do not agree because: a) the block of code I run using 'run section' consists of lines and the block itself has a certain line position in the script. It should be possible to know where in the script these lines are located and thus also where the error occurs; and b) if 'run section' is indeed exactly like running the code in the command line, then still the executed block of code consists of lines. Then at least the line number within the block could be known.. right?

The questions: Is it possible to make line numbers appear in the error message when running part of a script using 'run section'? If not, why is it technically not possible?

MWE:

```
   % this is my script

   %% this is a section with an error
   a(:) = zeros(1,2,3);
```

Save and run (F5) gives error with line number (5), Run section does not.

Using version R2013a, same behavior in R2016a

Comment: PS: This is not a duplicate, in my opinion, because the linked question does not ask about the technical (im)possibility.

Comment: I think that this is because "command line commands" don't add entries to the `dbstack`, which is the tool used for retrieving the files and lines in which errors occur. This may have something to do with how the MATLAB compiler operates. Instead of fighting it, I'd suggest saving these chunks of code into external "helper" functions and call them from your main script. Then you _will_ see the line numbers of the errors...

Comment: @Dev-iL Good suggestion but that would defeat the purpose of 'run section': quick debug of a section. So technically, your comment suggests 2 routes to solving this problem: 1) change the behavior of the 'command line commands' or 2) change 'run section' such that it runs sections as files. This might be possible with [programmatic access to the  editor](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/accessing-the-matlab-editor)

Comment: Where did you get the idea that "run section" was made for debugging? As far as I can tell, it was made so you don't have to select large chunks of code manually and "Evaluate Selection", which _may_ or _may not_ help debugging. I was merely repeating the age-old suggestion of "using the right tool for the job": if your code is so long that you can't debug it by stepping through it line-by-line, this is just more reason to split it into smaller functions. Also, consider that code blocks can start inside `if`/`for`/... constructs. Please do post an answer if you manage to solve it your way!

Comment: Can I start with "stepping through it line-by-line" at an arbitrary  position _without_ running the part before that position? If not, splitting the code is indeed a good solution, thanks.

Comment: Generally speaking, yes. You could run it _once_ until the section where you want to debug from, then save your entire workspace to a file, then you can quit debugging, reload the workspace, and start debugging from the point you want. Obviously, you don't really have to "run the code once" in the first place, but it might be easier/faster than artificially generating all the required variables with the right sizes and data types that are expected to exist at that stage during normal operation of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Dev-il's useful comments (and neglecting his good advice to sort my code better) I made a script which basically does what is asked: it runs the current section (based on the position of the cursor in the editor) by making a copy of the section and running it as a new script. This is done in such a way that line numbers are preserved, such that any error can be related to the lines in the original section.

Code:

`%% Copies currently selected section in editor to new file and runs it 
 filehandle = matlab.desktop.editor.getActive;
 code = filehandle.Text;
 pos = filehandle.Selection(1);

 % convert to line by line cell
 codeLines = strread(code,'%s','delimiter','\n','whitespace','');
 NL = numel(codeLines); % number of lines

 % find begin and end of current section
 % begin
 startSectionPos = [];
  for ilr = 1:pos 
    il = pos + 1 -ilr; % starting at pos and going up
    if isempty(startSectionPos) % not found yet
        % test if section start
         if ~isempty(regexpi(codeLines{il},'^(\s)*%%','start'))
             % this line contains %% at beginning of the line
             startSectionPos = il;     
         end
    else % we found it already
        codeLines{il} = ''; % delete lines 
    end
 end

 % end. we start at pos+1 if pos is start of section 
 endSectionPos = [];
 for il = (pos+(pos==startSectionPos)):NL % going down
    if isempty(endSectionPos) % not found yet
        % test if next section start
         if ~isempty(regexpi(codeLines{il},'^(\s)*%%','start'))
             % this line contains %% at beginning of the line
             endSectionPos = il-1; %previous section ended previous line
             codeLines{il} = ''; % delete line 

         end
    else % we found it already
        codeLines{il} = ''; % delete lines 
    end
 end
%%
%newCode = char(codeLines);
% save m file containing only selected section
filename = 'section.m';
fid = fopen(filename, 'wt');
fprintf(fid, '%s\n',codeLines{:});
fclose(fid);

% test if there are too many 'end's left at the end of the file
complaints = mlint(filename);
Nc = numel(complaints);
linesErr = [];
for icr = 1:Nc
    ic = Nc + 1 - icr; % start at bottom, go up
    if strcmpi(complaints(ic).message,'Parse error at END: usage might be invalid MATLAB syntax.')
        linesErr = [linesErr; complaints(ic).line];
    end
end
% fix loose ends
for il = 1:numel(linesErr)
     codeLines{linesErr(il)} = ''; % delete lines 
end

% write again
filename = 'section.m';
fid = fopen(filename, 'wt');
fprintf(fid, '%s\n',codeLines{:});
fclose(fid);    

%% run new file, give nice report if error
try
    run(filename)
catch err
    err.getReport
end`

Usage: 
Save code as runSection.m in your path. Work in editor. When you want to run a section, place your cursor in that section and either type 'runSection' in the Command Window or start runSection.m via a keyboard binding (shortcut) which can be set using the built-in [short cuts placed on Quick Access](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2012/09/19/the-matlab-r2012b-desktop-part-2-customizing-the-r2012b-matlab-desktop/#2bba4b23-8909-4bd9-a8b7-ea6ca0aa88f7). Now you can use alt-1 instead on control-enter to run your section! An alternative for setting the binding was [EditorMacro](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/editormacro-v2-setting-command-window-key-bindings), which is currently out-dated.